# In which path does Visual Studio Code install extensions?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

After installing an extension in Visual Studio Code, where do the files go?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

> **Where are extensions installed?**
>
> Extensions are installed in a per user extensions folder. Depending on your platform, the location is in the following folder:
>
> - Windows `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`
> - macOS `~/.vscode/extensions`
> - Linux `~/.vscode/extensions`

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-gallery#_common-questions

Answer (score 10):

**Alternative way to get to the extension folder**

Within VSCode, pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `p`, and type:
"Open Extension Folder". Then press enter.

It will take you to the `~/.vscode/extensions` folder