# How can I set up a default code for C++ in visual studio code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

In CodeBlocks it is possible to set up a code that will open each time you create a new file. Kind of a code template or skeleton.

How can I set up a default code to open in Visual Studio Code C++ so I don't have to write it each time I create a new file? I mean, instead of creating a blank file, I need it to show the following code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(){

}
```

Comment: https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=cantonios.project-templates

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-create-project-templates?view=vs-2019

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/73043147/836330 - file template snippets is now built-in to vscode (Insiders v1.70).  Demos in the link.  These snippets are NOT automatically added upon file creation.  If you must have that, see the extensions mentioned at https://stackoverflow.com/a/58460632/836330

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [File Template](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RalfZhang.filetemplate) extension.

C++ files are not included in its default list of supported file types. But it does support adding your own templates for [known VS Code language identifiers](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/languages/identifiers#_known-language-identifiers), such as `.cpp` for C++ files.

To set it up, follow the instructions on the [extension's page](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=RalfZhang.filetemplate):

1. Install the extension
2. Go to the extension's *templates* directory

   ```
   templates$ pwd
   /Users/gino/.vscode/extensions/ralfzhang.filetemplate-2.0.4/asset/templates
   ```

   - I am on macOS, and the path may vary per platform
   - See: [In which path does Visual Studio Code install extensions?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52831666/2745495)
3. Create a file named **cpp.tmpl**
4. Write your template code

   ```
   templates $ vim cpp.tmpl

   templates $ cat cpp.tmpl
   #include <iostream>

   using namespace std;

   int main(){

   }
   ```

To use it:

1. Restart VS Code (might not be needed, but just to be sure)
2. Create a file with a `.cpp` extension
3. Open the command list (<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> on Linux/Windows)
4. Run the command "**Tmpl: Create Template**"

[image: screenshot of VS Code with command palette]

The `.cpp` file will be populated by the contents of `cpp.tmpl`.

[image: screenshot of VS Code with generated C++ file]

If you want to be fancy with your template, according to the extension's documentation, the template follows the [TextMate syntax](https://macromates.com/manual/en/snippets). In my example above, I just used plain C++ code and it worked OK.

Comment: Is there anyway to do it automatically as soon as the file is created, or if not at least some configurable key short cut?

Comment: @PawanNirpal I don't know of a way to do this automatically on file creation. You have to remember that VS Code is an editor for *all* possible programming languages, I imagine it will be problematic to auto-fill a file on creation. As for keyboard shortcuts, this extension does not have one, but maybe some other extension supports it.

Answer (score 32):

1. Go to this [link](https://snippet-generator.app/).
2. Type/Paste the default code you want to use the snippet for. Enter the trigger and description.
3. Copy the generated snippet onto clipboard.
4. Head to VSC. Press `ctr + shift + p` .Type `configure user snippets`.
   5.Select your desired language(C++ in your case).
5. Replace the comments with the snippet in your clipboard.
6. Save and exit. Now try to type the trigger text. You will see the snippet ready!

Comment: Seems like adding a description and a trigger are compulsory.

Comment: link seems to be broken!

Answer (score 6):

## you can setup user snippet.

#### 1) click on setting icon select user snippets.

[image]

#### 2) select your language,cpp.

[image]

#### now enter snippet code,

(snippet code is in JSON)

```js
// Write this code in the cpp.json file
{
    "cpp snippets":
    {
        "prefix" : "basic",
                   "body" : [
                       "#include<iostream>",
                       "using namespace std;",
                       "int main()",
                       "{",
                       "    return 0;",
                       "}"
  
                   ],
                            "description" : "c++ basic"
    }
}
```

### Save this file, now open new .cpp file and just enter "basic" your snippet will appear !

to create custom snippet code, [check this](https://snippet-generator.app/?description=cp%20template&tabtrigger=&snippet=%23include%3Ciostream%3E%0A%0Ausing%20namespace%20std%3B%0A%20%0Aint%20main%28%29%7B%0A%0Acout%3C%3C%22hello%20world%22%3B%20%0A%0Areturn%200%0A%7D&mode=vscode)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to achieve this is by using [Auto Snippets Extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=andreasxp.auto-snippets) !
This method will write your default code automatically whenever you create a new .cpp file so you don't have to trigger the snipper manually.

**To Use the Extension:**

1. Install it from the Visual Studio Code store
2. Go to this [website](https://snippet-generator.app/) and type the code you won't to set it the default, also set the description to "cpp" on the website.
   [Very important point](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S9p7d.png)
3. Copy the generated snippet onto your clipboard.
4. Open VS Code, go to Command Palette <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd> or on mac <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>P</kbd>
5. Search for **>Configure User Snippets** click it then search for **cpp.json** then open the file.
6. Replace the comments with the snippet code in your clipboard.
7. Go to VS Code settings <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>,</kbd> on mac
8. Search for **Auto Snippets** then click **Edit in settings.json**

[it should shows you a code like that:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/faHGy.png)

Replace the `"snippet": "cpp-template"`  into  `"snippet": "cpp"`, Save the file <kbd>Ctl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on mac then close it!

Now every time you will create a new .cpp file it will write your default code automatically! :)